# TypeError: JSON.stringify(...).then is not a function - React JS

Tags: json, reactjs, express

I am trying to connect my react app with the backend for log in page. I am using a promise to return a success message.

login.js

```
    onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
              method : 'post',
              headers :{ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
              body : JSON.stringify({
                   userId : this.state.userId,
                   password : this.state.password
             }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(data => {
                    if(data === 'success'){
                            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
                    }
             })
        })
    }
```

Backend code -

```
  exports.findById = (req) => {
         return new Promise((resolve) => {
               var sql = "Select * from users where userid = '" + req.body.userId + "' ;";
               connection.query(sql,req,  function (error, results, fields) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)); 
                    var valid = false; 
                    if( data.length !=0 && req.body.userId === data[0].userid && req.body.password === data[0].password)
                         valid = true; 

                    if(valid) {
                         resolve({message : "success"});
                    }else{
                         reject({ message :"fail"});
                    }
              });
        })
  };
```

After clicking on sign in button, I am getting an error **"TypeError: JSON.stringify(...).then is not a function"**

I tried some solutions from similar questions, it did not work in my case.

Comment: you sure there is a JSON format data in variable `results`? and extra thing, I don't think is wise for u to passing sql query via javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `then` should be outside of `fetch`

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
    method : 'post',
    headers :{ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    body : JSON.stringify({
         userId : this.state.userId,
         password : this.state.password
   })
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if(data === 'success'){
            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo, `.then` should be on `fetch` not on `JSON.stringify`.

```js
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/", {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userId: this.state.userId,
      password: this.state.password
    })
  })
//-^
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data === "success") {
        this.props.onRouteChange("home");
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed a bracket. there should be a closing bracket after JSON.stringify().

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userId: this.state.userId,
      password: this.state.password
    })
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data === 'success') {
        this.props.onRouteChange('home');
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Check and confirm that you're not importing or requiring {JSON} in your application. It's most likely referring to that imported JSON rather than the global

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).